# How to access to a network share out of domain (IIS)

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions, windows-xp, network-share

It's been days that i'm struggling on this problem, but I wasn't able to find out a solution, nor to find anything related on Internet.

I developed a small web app for a customer, which collects data from a list of PCs working on some production lines.
Those PCs are just placed under their own workgroups: there is no domain, they are just linked together in a small LAN network, without any security credential (pretty weird, but it's not my business).

So, here's the problem.
I deployed my web app on a main PC running Win 7, all's good. 
Then, when i tried to open a .txt file located on a network share from a production line's PC (running Win XP), it gave me access denied error "Access to the path '\Andon10\SharedF\Andon.txt' is denied".

I really can't see why, there should be no access limit on the folder.
I gave at users 'Everyone' and 'Anonymous Logon' the Full Security & Sharing Permission on the folder (didn't work), Changed the Application Pool Identity User to 'NETWORK SERVICE' and back to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' (didn't work), Tried to change IIS authentication type (Anonymous and Windows Authentication), it didn't work.

Now i'm running out of ideas, i really can't find what's the problem here. 
I can easily open and edit the share using File Explorer, but not with IIS.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Write your answer by answering your question, not editing. We read and think about the possible solutions and then boom "I managed to solve my problem".....

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, but it was like 2 weeks I was losing my mind on this problem and, after asking for help here, two more days and Oh gosh, here's how to do that! My apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: I managed to solve my problem! The solution was to simply create some dedicated user on both the main PC and the destination PC, with same Username and Password. Using this account for Application Pool Identity solved the situation.

Now, I don't know if I have to delete this topic or if it should stay online for future purpose (that's my first question on this platform).

Comment: No problem but guess what. You can accept your own answer too. Crazy s..t right? :) have a nice day.